# Getting a key value from a dataframe by using 3-columns

Tags: python, dataframe, rows, key-value, numpy-slicing

Hey how to get a key value from a data frame by using 3-columns at once.

Here is the data frame named **ord_df** having the data like this,

```
    order_id              status          trading_symbol
211203202783445          COMPLETE            RELIANCE
211203202783449       TRIGGER PENDING        RELIANCE
```

I want to get the key value of **order_id** where **status** is **TRIGGER PENDING** and **trading_symbol** is **RELIANCE**.

And to get the value i'm using this line of code but it's not the right way i think and always gives me error.

```
order_id = ord_df.loc[(ord_df['tradingsymbol'] == RELIANCE) & (ord_df['status'].isin(["TRIGGER PENDING","OPEN"]))]["order_id"].values[0]
```

Perfect solution would be appreciated (:

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (2,), (1,))
Getting this as the error.